# Django AssertionError

Tags: python, django

```
    AssertionError at /api/purchases/person/

    It is redundant to specify `source='name'` on field 'Field' in
 serializer 'PurchaseSerializer', because it is the same as the field name. 
Remove the `source` keyword argument.
```

I assume it's referring to this code since I haven't use 'source' anywhere else:

```
class PurchaseSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.Field(source='name')

    class Meta:
        model = Purchase
        fields = ['name']
```

I'm trying to be able to filter purchases by "person" so I could only see their purchases BUT for some reason when I type a person that exists in the database it comes up with an Assertion error like above. If I type a person that does NOT exist in the database it throws no errors but returns an empty JSON. This should be vice versa but not sure why this isn't working.

Models.py

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Urls.py

```
url(r'^api/purchases/(?P<username>.+)/$', views.PurchaseList.as_view()),
```

Views.py

```
class PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the purchases for
        the user as determined by the username portion of the URL.
        """
        username = self.kwargs['username']
        return Purchase.objects.filter(name=username)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `source` keyword argument as the error message suggests:

```
class PurchaseSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.Field()
```

Comment: Your answer was slightly correct, it should be serializers.ReadOnlyField() it threw another error when I did it your way since I wasn't writing to the field only reading.